# Tableview data shown on label from table view

Tags: ios, json

I am new in iOS development and i want to know  when i click on row of table, my data which are shown in table view should be select on label. My label has name City.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you know about tableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method??

Comment: May be my way of formatting wrong but my problem is genuine..Could any one help??

Comment: I know about that but i didn't know what write in it??

Comment: check Uma's answer to use this `didSelect` method you have to set Delegate.

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad add this array

```
dataArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hyderabad",@"Bangalore",@"Chennai",@"Pune",@"Mumbai", nil];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    NSString *reUseid=@"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reUseid];

    if (cell==nil)

    {

        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reUseid];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = dataArr[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

**Here is TableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

     NSLog(@"selected is %@",[dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewToDescriptionSegue" sender:self];

}
```

in this method you got `indexpath` from that you can get selected row like `indexpath.row` and from that you can get object from array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/) method named didSelectRowAtIndexPath which get called up when user select any row. Get the value from your array at indexPath.row and set the text on your label.

Implement the below code on your project:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *name = [arrayname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [yourLabelInstance setText:name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a delegate method of `UITableView` which is called when you tap on cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    city.text = [arrayname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: One more thing..Could I ask one more problem?If you permited me?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a delegate method of UITableView which is called when you touch/select any row in table.

Here, using *indexPath* parameter you can access currently selected row index. You can access data from datasource array having selected row index.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *strCity = [arrCity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [lblCity setText:strCity];

}
```